# Add created_at field on admin side of product information page in magento

Tags: magento, admin, catalog

I want to add created_at field on admin side of `Catalog -> Manage product -> General` tab.

It should be update. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add created_at on `Catalog -> Manage Product -> General` because of it is magento default product attribute. You can chose display different attribute name, it will display on General tab.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own attribute in setup file of your module. And use model Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created. In this case your attribute will be use data of create_at attribute.

Try this code:

```
$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'go_live_date',
    array(
        'type'       => 'datetime',
        'input'      => 'datetime',
        'label'      => 'Date of Creation',
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'required'   => false,
        'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created'
    )
);
```